# how to draw bounding ellipses in java cv?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I want to draw all the ellipses in an image and put bounding ellipses on them like here http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html?highlight=ellipses

The problem is that I don't know how to convert the code into javaCV code.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the corresponding Java calls here: http://docs.opencv.org/java/. The API is exactly the same so you can pretty much directly use C++ code.

For example if you want to draw an ellipse simply use the [Core.ellipse](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#ellipse(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Point,%20org.opencv.core.Size,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar)) function.